# JavaScript or jQuery file with same script different place its different

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have problem with jQuery or JavaScript. i use bootstrap css framework. in this problem i have a same script that i put in different place. but the script doesnot work at all. you can see the snipped to help me. i use bootstrap css framework i doubt and i dont know how to make the all same script with different place in the page is diffrent. i dont understand with the last one. hope your understand. Thanks in advance!

```js
/* this the script.js */

$("#image").find("img").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            getClass = $this.attr('img')
            splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
            if(splitClass[1] <= 20) {
                $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");

            } else if(splitClass[1] >= 40) {
                $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

            } else {
                $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div id="image">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img id="img-1" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif" />
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img id="img-2" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif" />
   </div>
  </div>
 <!---this the script---->
     <script src="script.js"></script>
 </div>
</div>
<!------ Many Text in here ------------>
 <p>the script in top is working but the script in bottom is not working because there is same script. how can i set be same work. with only one script the text must be in here. help me</p>
  
<!----------------------> 
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div id="image">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img id="img-3" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif" />
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img id="img-4" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif" />
   </div>
  </div>
 <!---this the same script with the top script---->
     <script src="script.js"></script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or any kind of information logged in the console?

Comment: @amura.cxg what you mean?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/69Lkwpuo/

Comment: ids should be unique - if you are trying to do a selector on the repeated id then it will only select the first element with that id it comes to.  Change the repeated ids to a class and base your selector on that (it will also mean you don't need to include the script multiple times)

Comment: The title and what you are asking is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#image img").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    getClass = $this.attr('img')
    splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
    if(splitClass[1] <= 20) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");

    } else if(splitClass[1] >= 40) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

    } else {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69Lkwpuo/1/)

---In your original code `$("#image").find("img")` would only select the first `div` with id `#image`. Whereas `$("#image img")` will select all `img`s that are a child of an element with the id `#image`.

Why `find()` doesn't seem to work on each element returned by `$("#image")` I'm not sure. If someone can explain this I'd love to hear it.---

As Pete has pointed out, the original selector was an id which will only return the first matching element. See the solution below that uses a class instead.

**Edit**

As has been pointed out, ids should be unique. Below is better solution in which duplicate ids are not used.

```
$(".image img").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        getClass = $this.attr('img')
    splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
    if (splitClass[1] <= 20) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");

    } else if (splitClass[1] >= 40) {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

    } else {
        $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69Lkwpuo/3/)

Comment: in response to why find doesn't work on "each" element returned by `$("#image")` - it will only ever return one element - it is an id therefore will only select the first element with that id it comes to as ids are meant to be unique

Comment: is the image src on javascript only can loader with the source "http:"?  i want using it offline.  not connected to the internet.  is that can?

Comment: @Pete thanks, I didn't realize that. I never use multiple Ids so I just assumed they worked the same as other selectors.

Comment: @Pete can you help me answer the question with your think?  thank you

Comment: @KarlFriedchicken are these bits of code being added dynamically (is that the reason for including the script everytime?)  If not, I would just do as the second fiddle above, but instead of including the script everytime, just run it once on document ready.  If so, then when you run the script (still only once on doc ready), you will need to use a [delegated selector](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)